# Jacobson radical need a finite number of maximal ideals?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

**All about I'm going to write is based on commutative rings with unit.**

Is known that given a ring $R$, the Jacobson ideal of $R$ is the set

$$J(R)=\{ x\in R\mid 1-ax\in R^{\times}, \forall a\in R \}$$

But also is known as the intersection of all the maximal ideals $I\subset R$.

My question is: **In this second definition is needed to have a finite number (or numerable) of maximal ideals or not?**

Why this question? It comes from this problems:

> - Let $M$ be an $A$-module finitely generated. If $\mathfrak{a}M=M$, then there exists $x\in \mathfrak{a}$ such that $(1+x)M=0$.
> - If $M$ is finitely generated and $\mathfrak{m}M=M$ for all maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, then $M=0$.

My interest is from the last one. My idea was:

Since for all the maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}M=M$, then I can consider the product of all the maximal ideals, and you can make $\prod_{i\in I}\mathfrak{m}_iM=M$, but all the maximal ideals are coprime between them, so

$$\prod_{i\in I}\mathfrak{m}_i=\cap_{i\in I}\mathfrak{m}_i=J(R)M$$

And from the point before, there is an element $x\in J(R)$ such that $(1+x)M=0$. Because of this, since $x\in J(R)$, $1+(-1)x$ is an unit, and $(1-x)M=M$, so this implies that $1=0$, and then $M=0$.

Comment: The usual proof is to localize $M=mM$ at $m$ and (from Nakayama) get $M_m=0$ for all $m$. This leads to $M=0$.

Comment: @monsieur Just take a look at the radical of $\mathbb Z$. No finite intersection of maximal ideals (and no finite intersection of any set of nonzero ideals) will ever get you the radical ($\{0\}$).

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no requirement that there be only finitely many maximal ideals in the second definition.

To solve your problem even if there are infinitely many maximal ideals, I would suggest considering the ideal of all elements $r\in R$ such that $rM=0$.  What can you say about this ideal?

Comment: If that ideal has an element different than $0$, it means that all the elements are zero divisors, don't?

Comment: $M$ is a module, not an ideal, so I don't know what you mean by that.  Your goal is to show that the ideal is $R$ itself (that is, it is not a proper ideal).  How can you relate the question of whether an ideal is proper to maximal ideals?

Comment: Now I understand my mistake.